# How can i do set function for object when i creat new object from registerComponent

Tags: aframe, webvr

I want to create a new object and it has "move" function when it is maked from a registerComponent.

I try setAttribute('function Name') and setAttribute('attribute','function Name'),but both don't work.

for example :

```
            AFRAME.registerComponent('objectMake',
            {
                init:function()
                {

                },
                tick: function()
                {
                    var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
                    if (condition == true) 
                    {
                        var boxEl = document.createElement('a-box');

                        boxEl.setAttribute('material',{color:'#CC0000'});
                        boxEl.setAttribute('position',{x:Math.random()*20-10,y:Math.random()*20-10,z:Math.random()*20-10});
                        boxEl.setAttribute('scale',{x:Math.random()/2,y:Math.random()/2,z:Math.random()/2});
                        boxEl.setAttribute('attribute','move');
                        sceneEl.appendChild(boxEl);
                    }
                }

            });
```

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('move', 
            {               
                tick: function()
                {
                    var targetItem = document.querySelector('a-box');
                    var targetPosition = targetItem.getAttribute('position');
                    this.el.setAttribute('position',
                    {
                        x: targetPosition.x,
                        y: targetPosition.y,
                        z: targetPosition.z-0.1
                    });
                }
            });
```

How can I do or how can i improve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It doesn't quite make sense what you are doing. `move` is a string that has no meaning and `setAttribute('attribute')` also has no meaning. Perhaps double check the documentation and guides again to get started.

Comment: @ngokevin
uhh sorry, I may not have expressed it clearly.
I mean in registerCompenent to setting new object attribute,I want set other registerComponent for that .

example:
`objectMake` is make a `<a-entity objectMake><a-entity>`
but i want
 `<a-entity objectMake  move><a-entity>`
how can i set registerComonent"move" for entity in "objectMake"?

Comment: `this.el.setAttribute('move', '');`